# how put lwjgl 3 on the apache netBeans (error with the dependicies)

Tags: java, dependencies, pom.xml, libraries, lwjgl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcgYA.png)
hello there, im new here, i have a problem with lwjgl, i dont have idea how put the libreries of lwjgl 3 (with maven) on the IDE apache netBeans, i put the libreries on the IDE and i have this error and this is the code.
and thank you for your help  c:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>bacterybattlebeta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
       <lwjgl.version>3.3.3-SNAPSHOT</lwjgl.version>
    <joml.version>1.10.5</joml.version>
    <lwjgl3-awt.version>0.1.8</lwjgl3-awt.version>
    <steamworks4j.version>1.9.0</steamworks4j.version>
    <steamworks4j-server.version>1.9.0</steamworks4j-server.version>
    <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-nfd</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-nfd</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
        <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joml</groupId>
        <artifactId>joml</artifactId>
        <version>${joml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lwjglx</groupId>
        <artifactId>lwjgl3-awt</artifactId>
        <version>${lwjgl3-awt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.code-disaster.steamworks4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>steamworks4j</artifactId>
        <version>${steamworks4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.code-disaster.steamworks4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>steamworks4j-server</artifactId>
        <version>${steamworks4j-server.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

im tried to put the libraries i the IDE and dont work and i dont know what to do

Comment: yeah, i resolve the problem, i dont know what i do but it works, i was go to the options of the proyect and i think i go to the option of "reload POM" and that put all the dependencies on the protect.
now, i have another error!
in a part of the test code are a error.
this say "lambda expessions are not supported in- source 5"

Comment: You can specify `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>` in the `<properties>` section of pom.xml.